# How use reduce() to concat an array and delete the items duplicated

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reduce

I have a problem using the reduce function in JavaScript. My goal is to take an array of arrays and, using reduce, then concat all the values and delete the duplicates:

I have an array like this:
firstArray = [[1, 2],[2, 3, 4],[4, 5, 6]]

I need an array like this after apply reduce():
resultArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

```
const arrayElements = [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]];
const newArray = arrayElements.reduce((total, value) => {
    return total.concat(value);
}, []);
```

This is the fragment that I have, this only concat all the values, this is to say, [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Comment: Simple indexOf or includes check before concating the value would do the trick

Comment: `const newArray = [...new Set(arrayElements.flat())];`

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]];
var unique_numbers = [].concat(...num);
unique_numbers = Array.from(new Set(unique_numbers ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

```js
const array = [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]];
const newArray = [...new Set(array.flat(Infinity))]

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: flat is an experimental feature, it will not work in most browsers.

Comment: @DanielOrmeño not in most, just IE and edge, it will work on every other browser, and you can use polyfill for that

Comment: Edge will eventually be using Chromium :)

Comment: Firefox vs 60.7 throws an error `"TypeError: array.flat is not a function"`

Answer (score 0):

Your reduce is correct, just add the data to a set, and convert the set to an array using spread syntax `...`

```js
const arrayElements = [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]];
const newArray = [...new Set(arrayElements.reduce((total, value) => total.concat(value), []))];

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `Set`:

```
const newArray = arrayElements.reduce((accum, arr) => [...accum, ..arr], [])
const arrNoDupes = [...new Set(newArray)]
```

or using `filter`:

```
const newArray = arrayElements.reduce((accum, arr) => [
  ...accum
  ...arr.filter(value => !accum.includes(value))
], [])
```

These are just two ways you can do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the old fashioned ES5 way in case browser support is a concern.

```js
var arrayElements = [[1,2],[2,3,4],[5,6]];
var newArray = arrayElements.reduce(function(total, value){
  return total.concat(value).filter(function (x, i, a) { 
    return a.indexOf(x) == i; 
  });
}, []);
console.log(newArray)
```